# Как преобразовать число в строку? Нужна функция

Tags: c++

Знаю функцию "atof" для преобразования строки в число float, но нужно обратную.
 Нашел 'itoa' , но компилятор не узнает функцию, какую библиотеку использовать, те что нашёл не помогают. Быть может в новой версии с++ убрали, может знает кто, решение данной проблемы ? Либо другую функцию, делающую то же самое. P.s. Ошибся в начале. Написал нужно преобразовать строку в число.

Comment: `sprintf` подойдет?

Comment: itoa сокращенно integer to ascii и она не является стандартом) судя по вопросу вам наоборот, попробуйте atoi

Comment: `std::to_string`

Comment: Упс, ошибся наоборот. Нужно число перевести в строку

Comment: Функции `itoa` никогда не существовало. Поэтому никакое "в новой версии с++ убрали" тут ни при чем.

Answer (score -1):

Вариантов много. Можно просто to_string(число), можно

```
float num = 42.123;
    std::ostringstream ost;
    ost << num;
    string temp = ost.str();
    std::cout << "As string: " << temp << std::endl;
```

Но для этого нужно подключить библиотеки:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
```